# .htaccess block all ip except mine but my ip is Non-Unique

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im using satellite wi-fi internet and I blocked visits to my test webpage where I'm doing all kinds of changes first and then apply them into the live website. On this point, I found out to block others access including search engine robots with `.htaccess` ip block except my ip. But the problem is; Today I realized that every person who uses same brand satellite wi-fi has the same ip adress and they can visit my page. Is there any solution for this?

The reason im not using local domain to have a test page is; this way is not platform and computer dependent and also as it is identically same with original, I don't have to remove some codes or tags before copy it into live. I just upload it and there is no problem. My main aim while doing this is; not to recognized as duplicate and listed by search engines when they type my website name. I thought to add some php code and create a session variable to check if not exist, redirect to orginal page, but in this way, I have to include it on each page one by one and when im done with editing, if I forget to remove that and put it to live there will be problems until i realize.

Comment: IP is not user unique

Comment: You need to get up to speed with a proper development workflow that allows you to develop locally and deploy to production later (and possibly a testing and/or staging server before). It is entirely possible to do so without having to edit individual details before uploading.

Comment: is using a .htpasswd file an option?

Comment: @TahaPaksu is there any link that could help me with it? Never heard and sound good.

Comment: Go read up on _HTTP Auth_, and how to configure it in Apache.

Comment: https://www.web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator you can use this page to generate a .htpasswd file and read how to configure the .htaccess file to use the generated .htpasswd file. I guess this will be enough for you to protect your webpage from unwanted network access.

Comment: @TahaPaksu Thank you very much. Eyvallah =)

Comment: You're welcome. Kolay gelsin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache HTTP Server can use a .htpasswd file referenced from a .htaccess file to create restricted protected areas. The .htpasswd file contains rows corresponding to a pair of username and password separated with a colon character. The password is encrypted using the UNIX system's crypt method and may use MD5 or SHA1.

Once set up, a user wishing to access a restricted directory will be requested a username and password pair to gain access. Only correct pairs will grant access to the requested directory.

http://web2generators.com/apache-tools/htpasswd-generator

You can use this page to generate a .htpasswd file and read how to configure the .htaccess file to use the generated .htpasswd file. I guess this will be enough for you to protect your webpage from unwanted network access.

Or, you can manually generate with the htpasswd command provided by your Apache configuration.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html

Comment: I have implemented the .htpasswd and its really what i was looking for. Thank you very much.